# String.split bug?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I was messing around with some split strings operations.

It occurred to me that by doing that it returns a string

```js
var name = 'aaaa bbbb cccc'.split();
console.log(name)
console.log(typeof name)
```

However, this returns an array:

```js
  console.log('aaaa bbbb cccc'.split());
  console.log(typeof 'aaaa bbbb cccc'.split())
```

Am I missing something? I did not find anything else on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (didn't bother looking RFC) and I don't know what is happening.
Anyone could help me here?

Comment: Change your first example to use `let` or `const` or change `name` to be something else (like `foo`). By using `var name` you're clashing with [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) which converts its type to a string

Comment: Best to just avoid `var` entirely, it has a lot of odd behavior that's pretty much never what you want unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks very much, @NickParsons.
@JohnMontgomery I quickly use the console for iterations when I am in doubt. That is why I use the `var` I will change that behavior to `let` from now on.